# correct Installation and configuration of openJDK and R

Tags: java, openjdk, r

I am relatively new to Ubuntu so I wont know a lot of commands that probably became standard to a lot of you guys.
I am trying to set up R and with it the necessary java dependencies to install e.g. JGR, rjava, etc. I read through quite a few instructions to do that but somehow I must have done sth wrong. Here is the state of R and java:

```
R --version

R version 2.14.1 (2011-12-22)
Copyright (C) 2011 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
ISBN 3-900051-07-0
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

java -version

java version "1.6.0_23"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11pre) (6b23~pre11-0ubuntu1.11.10.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b11, mixed mode)

R CMD javareconf

Java interpreter : /usr/bin/java
Java version     : 1.6.0_23
Java home path   : /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre
Java compiler    : /usr/bin/javac
Java headers gen.: /usr/bin/javah
Java archive tool: /usr/bin/jar
Java library path: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/../lib/amd64:/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jni:/lib:/usr/lib
JNI linker flags : -L/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/amd64/server -L/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/amd64 -L/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/../lib/amd64 -L/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64 -L/usr/lib/jni -L/lib -L/usr/lib -ljvm
JNI cpp flags    :
```

But when I try to install 'JavaGD' in R, which is a dependency for JGR I get:

```
...
checking Java support in R... present:
interpreter : '/usr/bin/java'
cpp flags   : ''
java libs   : '-L/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/amd64/server -L/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/amd64 -L/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/../lib/amd64 -L/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64 -L/usr/lib/jni -L/lib -L/usr/lib -ljvm'
configure: error: One or more Java configuration variables are not set.
Make sure R is configured with full Java support (including JDK). Run
R CMD javareconf
as root to add Java support to R.
...
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not familiar with R but based on your console it seems like R is requiring a JDK while you have a JRE as you default JAVA home variable.
I would suggest you to make sure you have the JDK installed or install it (`sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jdk`).
Also make sure that your JAVA_HOME environment variable is pointing to the JDK and not to the JRE (you can see in your output that currently the *java home path* is set to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre`.

Comment: openjdk-6-jdk is installed. When I set the path to /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk I still get the same error

Comment: yossile advised the path `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre`

Comment: irrelevant answer
the import info from the log is the last line : need to be run by root

(as mentioned in other replies)

Answer (score 7):

One shouldn't blindly install `openjdk-6-jdk`. What helped me, was to change the version of Java. Fortunately there is a nice Ubuntu tool for doing that:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

There you can see, what Javas are already available on system, and set the desired one. And then install either `openjdk-7-jdk` or `openjdk-6-jdk` (or both)

and *only* then run

```
sudo R CMD javareconf
```

More details about Java choices are on [Ubuntu's Community Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java)

P.S. For people coming here from Google: Among other things, this post helps solving issues with rj instalation in R, with error message: `R is not configured with full Java support. Please make sure an JDK is installed and run R CMD javareconf`. When I did that, it said: `NOTE: Your JVM has a bogus java.library.path system property!`. So: *no need messing with Java's library paths!*.

Comment: this worked for me on ubuntu 16.04, but i had to launch R using `sudo -i R`

Answer (score 3):

> R CMD javareconf as root

means, you have to use sudo, to issue your command:

```
sudo R CMD javareconf
```

You will get asked for your password (your normal userpassword).

Comment: all the commands above where executed as root user through sudo -su at the start of the session. Sorry, forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 0):

Yossiles answer helped me on the way, but here is the newbie-friendly version, which also draws on [the answer to this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/175514/how-to-set-java-home-for-openjdk).

What worked for me was was this:-

1) open /etc/environment in your favorite txteditor:

```
sudo gedit /etc/environment
```

2) add a new line with "JAVA_HOME" and the path to correct jr-directory, in the case of java 8, it is:

```
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre"
```

3) source the updated environment and check the variable:

```
source /etc/environment
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

4) update the java-R configuration like this:

```
sudo R CMD javareconf
```

5) install RJava, XLConnect or whatever java-dependent R-package you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [update-alternatives](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/vivid/man8/update-alternatives.8.html) is the most convenient *linking* mechanism to maintain different JVM versions - even from different providers like Oracle / OpenJDK. I am open to correction but I would say one needs a JDK and not only a JVM for R setup.

The outline to prepare for R JAVA configuration are:

1. ensure that the required JVM is correctly located in `/usr/lib/jvm`
2. setup the *linking* using `update-alternatives --install` for each JAVA command required by R
3. use `update-alternatives --configure` to select a default JVM
4. refresh the R configuration

To ensure that the JDK is already in the correct location, query the list of installed JVMs with the command

```
ls /usr/lib/jvm
```

If the folder does not include a JDK then relocate the entire JVM folder from the extracted `tar.gz` (download) to `/usr/lib/jvm` with the command:

```
sudo mv <JDK folder> /usr/lib/jvm
```

separate terminal entries for update-alternatives is required by R for the following JAVA commands:

- interpreter : '/usr/bin/java'
- archiver    : '/usr/bin/jar'
- compiler    : '/usr/bin/javac'
- header prep.: '/usr/bin/javah'

the entries for `jdk1.8.0_51` are as follows:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_51/bin/java" 2

sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/jar" "jar"  "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_51/bin/jar" 2

sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac"  "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_51/bin/javac" 2

sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javah" "javah"  "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_51/bin/javah" 2
```

NB. the output after execution of `update-alternatives --install` for JVM `jdk1.8.0_51` should be similar output to:

> update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_51/bin/java to
>   provide /usr/bin/java (java) in auto mode

to select the required JVM as default

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

If only a single JVM is setup then the following output is presented in the terminal

> There is only one alternative in link group java (providing
>   /usr/bin/java): /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_51/bin/java Nothing to
>   configure.

alternatively the relevant entry# for the required JVM must be selected

to check that the correct JVM is linked

```
java --version
```

finally, update the R setup with:

```
sudo R CMD javareconf
```

Note that this setup could not seem to be working if you have attempted other ways to "hardwire" configure your JVM