# How to set JAVA_HOME for Java?

Tags: java

I've installed a version of Java. How can we set the `$JAVA_HOME` environment variable correctly?

Answer (score 526, accepted):

You can set your `JAVA_HOME` in `/etc/profile` as [Petronilla Escarabajo](https://askubuntu.com/a/175519/19723) suggests. But the preferred location for `JAVA_HOME` or any system variable is `/etc/environment`.

Open `/etc/environment` in any text editor like `nano` or `gedit` and add the following line:

```
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/open-jdk"
```

(java path could be different)

Use `source` to load the variables, by running this command:

```
source /etc/environment
```

Then check the variable, by running this command:

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

**Update**

Usually most linux systems source /etc/environment by default. If your system doesn't do that add the following line to `~/.bashrc` (Thanks @pje)

```
source /etc/environment
```

Comment: When i tried to run Android Studio (that has IntelliJ IDEA as a base), i had an error message very similar to @advocate's: "'tools.jar' seems to be not in Android Studio classpath." After fiddling a lot with JAVA_HOME without success, i decided to take a look at studio.sh, the shellscript that starts Android Studio. As a wild guess, i set JDK_HOME to the same value expected for JAVA_HOME, and voila! It installed without great problems.

Comment: how to set multiple paths for different JDKs http://paste.ubuntu.com/13151297/  will work??

Comment: This setting seems temporary. After restarting the pc, we have to source it again

Comment: For those doing software development, don't put your JAVA_HOME in /etc/environment unless you want to reboot everytime you switch JDK versions.

Comment: This is a temporary solution, as others pointed out. No one would want to run source every time they restart their bash.

Comment: As others have pointed out, this doesn't stick between terminal sessions. What I did to address this is just added the line `source /etc/environment` to the top of my bash config file `~/.bashrc` so that it loads all my environment settings on startup. Working for me so far.

Comment: @ManulaWaidyanatha pje's comment should be included in your answer. It's not practical to do 'source /etc/environment' every time we open a new terminal.

Comment: @sedulam  I updated the answer

Comment: @HDave If not /etc/environment, then where should you the JAVA_HOME assignment then?

Comment: @RobertOschler @HDave you don't need to restart your servers everytime. You can use the `source` command to reload the configurations.

Comment: in ubuntu 18.04 I can see variable set when doing "echo $JAVA_HOME" but it is not listed in output of "printenv" - why?

Comment: Sourcing /etc/environment doesn't work for me (19.04). See https://superuser.com/questions/339617/how-to-reload-etc-environment-without-rebooting

Comment: `ls: cannot access '/usr/lib/jvm/open-jdk': No such file or directory`

Comment: @Damien Nowadays (23.10) if you have it installed through apt like `default-jdk` or `default-jre`, you should find it at `JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/default-java"`. It's a symlink that points to whichever the current one is on the same folder. Best option if you always want to use the latest one installed.

Answer (score 87):

To set `JAVA_HOME` environment variable, do the following:

1. Launch Terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard.
2. Enter the following command:
   $ `gksudo gedit /etc/environment`
3. Depending on where you installed your Java, you will need to provide the full path. For this example, I installed Oracle JDK 7 in the `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle` directory.
   Scroll to the end of the file and enter the following:
   `JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle`
   `export JAVA_HOME`
4. Save your file and exit **gedit**.
5. Lastly, reload the system PATH with the following command:
   $ `. /etc/environment`

The above method will save you the hassle in having to run the commands every time you log in to your computer.

Comment: How does  .  /etc/environment work?

Comment: Is the addition of the `export` command necessary in the `/etc/environment` ?

Comment: @pkaramol I've had to add export JAVA_HOME on 16.04LTS to make it load at startup.

Comment: @adeen-s You added `export` to a line in `/etc/environment` and it helped? That file contains variable definitions parsed as `=`-delimited name-value pairs; its contents are not executed as commands. (See [`man pam_env`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/pam_env.8.html).) So unless you're *separately* treating the file as though it were a script (such as by passing `/etc/environment` to bash's `.`/`source` builtin), I wouldn't expect that to work.

Comment: > How does . /etc/environment work?  
-- . (dot) loads commands from a file
https://askubuntu.com/a/232938/189965

Comment: I am doubtful if this will persist the JAVA_HOME path for all future sessions? I followed the above steps. But after I logged out and logged in again echo $JAVA_HOME does not give the Java installation path.Any reason why?

Answer (score 50):

If you do not know the path and you only have openJDK installed, you can type 
`update-alternatives --config java` and you should find the path. To set the variable you can write `JAVA_HOME=<PATH>` followed by `export JAVA_HOME`. Notice there's no space when declaring the variable. To check if the variable is stored you simply type `echo $JAVA_HOME` to verify.

Comment: This seems like it would be static.  If I remove openjdk-7 and install openjdk-9, won't the JAVA_HOME then point to the wrong place?  How can it be made dynamic?

Comment: By you manually changing it.  Once again, YOU are the way it becomes dynamic....

Comment: What @HDave means is that In certain cases, you may want JAVA_HOME to point to a specific java version, so making the update of JAVA_HOME dynamic may not be what you want.

Comment: i like this answer.  I tested with echo and see my path.  However, I am confused why I am still getting **JAVA_HOME** environment variable is not set  when I run mvn -version

Comment: I wrote this answer back when I was more ignorant. Setting the variable as described will only affect your current terminal session, and will not be persisted. The correct way is to run 

`update-alternatives --install <link> <name> <target> <priority>`

for example:
`update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/jvm/default-runtime/bin/java 1`

Answer (score 1):

**This is the best option if you always want to use the latest one installed.**
Nowadays (Ubuntu 23.10) you should probably have it installed through apt like:

```sh
sudo apt install default-jdk # or default-jre
```

In this case, you should find it at `/usr/lib/jvm/default-java`.
It's a symlink that points to whichever the current JVM is on the same folder.
So, just run this to add the environment as a separate file:

```sh
sudo nano /etc/environment.d/90java.conf
```

Add this line and save:

```sh
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/default-java"
```

Then reboot or login again, or `source /etc/environment.d/90java.conf` to load it on the current shell.