# In a bash script what does a dot followed by a space and then a path mean?

Tags: command-line, bash, openvz

I came across this example when trying to mount a usb device inside a openvz container and I have never seen the construct in the second line before. Can you explain what it signifies?

```
#!/bin/bash
. /etc/vz/vz.conf
```

Answer (score 108):

It's a synonym of the builtin `source`. It will *execute commands from a file in the current shell*, as read from `help source` or `help .`.

In your case, the file `/etc/vz/vz.conf` will be executed (very likely, it only contains variable assignments that will be used later in the script). It differs from just executing the file with, e.g., `/etc/vz/vz.conf` in many ways: the most obvious is that the file doesn't need to be executable; then you will think of running it with `bash /etc/vz/vz.conf` but this will only execute it in a child process, and the parent script will not see any modifications (e.g., of variables) the child makes.

**Example:**

```
$ # Create a file testfile that contains a variable assignment:
$ echo "a=hello" > testfile
$ # Check that the variable expands to nothing:
$ echo "$a"

$ # Good. Now execute the file testfile with bash
$ bash testfile
$ # Check that the variable a still expands to nothing:
$ echo "$a"

$ # Now _source_ the file testfile:
$ . testfile
$ # Now check the value of the variable a:
$ echo "$a"
hello
$
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Just a note: `.` will work in most shells (sh, ash, ksh, etc), `source` is specific for bash.

Comment: @EarlGray `source` isn't *just* bash--it's in C-style shells ([`csh`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/bsd-csh.1.html), [`tcsh`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/tcsh.1.html))--and zsh too. `.` works in Bourne-style shells including [those listed](http://askubuntu.com/q/232932#comment288304_232938). Considering that bash is a Bourne-style shell and hardly any bash script of non-trivial complexity is likely to run in a C-style shell, it's true `.` should be considered much more portable. But bash's `source` synonym of `.` exists partly for portability.

Comment: @EliahKagan yes, you're right; it's better to say that `.` is universally portable and `source` is wide-spread, but does not work in plain `sh`.

Answer (score 5):

> When a script is run using `source' it runs within the existing shell, any variables created or modified by the script will remain available after the script completes.

Syntax
      . filename [arguments]

```
  source filename [arguments]
```