# Cannot set an environment variable using a Bash script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, environment-variables

I want to set an environment variable from a bash script that I wrote.  So I created a bash script and called it `set.sh`. Its content is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

export DEV_SRC="/home/m/mydata/sourecCode"
echo $DEV_SRC
```

When I run this script, the output is

```
/home/m/mydata/sourecCode
```

But if I run this code on the same terminal that I ran the above script from,

```
echo $DEV_SRC
```

I cannot see any value, so I think the value is not exported.

Why is the value not exported?

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/26411/18193) if you just want to set some environment variables without having to use a bash script.

Comment: To make it work in the parent shell, you need to *source* the file rather than just executing it - see for example [In a bash script what does a dot followed by a space and then a path mean?](https://askubuntu.com/a/232938/178692)

Answer (score 5):

By default `bash` creates a copy of the current environment, executes the script in this environment, then destroys the copy.

To execute a script in the *current* environment you should use this syntax:

```
. /home/m/mydata/sourecCode
echo $DEV_SRC
```

or

```
source /home/m/mydata/sourecCode
echo $DEV_SRC
```