# sh script - question about single line

Tags: bash, scripts, sh

I have this bash script:

```
#!/bin/sh -eux

. ./.env
```

What does the second line do?

It seems to be impossible to google such syntax :)

Comment: I would search for "dotenv" and "dot operator bash"

Comment: That helped. Answer is here https://askubuntu.com/questions/232932/in-a-bash-script-what-does-a-dot-followed-by-a-space-and-then-a-path-mean

Comment: The second line doesn't do anything .. it is empty ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the dot:

> . (source or dot operator)
>
> Read and execute commands from the filename argument in the current
>   shell context.
>
> Syntax
>         . filename [arguments]
>
> ```
>   source filename [arguments]
> ```
>
> source is a synonym for dot/period '.' in bash, but not in POSIX sh,
>   so for maximum compatibility use the period.

And regarding

```
./.env
```

That is a hidden file (starts with a dot) called `.env` in the current directory (`./`)

Basically this command sources the file `.env` and from the filename you can assume it reloads environment variables. It is equivalent to

```
source ./.env
```