# How to set java home?

Tags: 12.10, java

Can any one tell me, how to set java home in Ubuntu 12.10?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set JAVA\_HOME for OpenJDK?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/175514/how-to-set-java-home-for-openjdk)

Answer (score 7):

Open terminal by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and execute following command:

```
gedit ~/.bashrc
```

Now go to end of file and add the following lines:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/path/to/jdk/folder
#usually /usr/java/jdk or /usr/lib/java/jdk
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

Now in terminal type:

```
sudo source ~/.bashrc
```

This will make it appear on every terminal if open.

Now you can cross check it by typing following line in terminal

```
echo $PATH
```

It will show you path of your jdk at the end

For more information visit [this link](http://daksh21ubuntu.blogspot.in/2012/08/how-to-set-environment-variable.html)

Comment: You don't need to use sudo to edit your own .bashrc, but it still works, so +1

Answer (score 2):

Try This:

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java
export JAVA_HOME
PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export PATH
```

This should work, but make sure to change `/usr/lib/jvm/java` with your java path.

Answer (score 1):

Well that will be easy, just open terminal and do

- For one user

  ```
  gedit ~/.bash_profile
  ```
- For all users

  ```
  gedit /etc/profile
  ```

And just add line like this

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/java/jdk1.5.0_07/bin
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/java/jdk1.5.0_07/bin
```

Just make sure that path is right. And if you did it for all users you will need to activate it using

```
sudo source /etc/profile
```

Source: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-set-java_home-path-variable/

Answer (score 1):

To set JAVA_HOME for all users do as Follows:

```
sudo gedit /etc/environment
JAVA_HOME =":usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin" 
CLASSPATH =":usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin:/home/something etc whatever you want etc"( separated by semicolon )
```

Answer (score 0):

I installed Java 11 in Ubuntu 20.04 by setting `JAVA_HOME` for the same...

Check your Ubuntu version:

```
$ lsb_release -d
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
```

find out the location of your jvm:

```
$ whereis jvm
jvm: /usr/lib/jvm
```

open `.bashrc` in any editor of your choice:

```
$ nano ~/.bashrc
```

add the following lines to it:

```bsh
## setting JAVA_HOME
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
export JAVA_HOME
    
PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export PATH
```

now your `JAVA_HOME` is set.

Open a terminal and enter the command to confirm the setup:

```
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
```

This will output the same path you've set just now.