# Cannot open Android project first time in new install of Android SDK in Eclipse IDE

Tags: 16.04, eclipse, plugins, android-sdk

**Primary topic:**

Please help me with a problem encountered in attempt to begin Android project in Eclipse. Please note that I want to use Eclipse and not to install another IDE.

**Secondary:**

I want to know if this Eclipse/Android environment has this many bugs in daily use as well. Only (yes, only) if this is the case I would want to know what practical solution is there to develop Android applications on a low-profile Ubuntu PC.

**Problem:**

- Ran New Android project wizard in Eclipse first time after install of the Android SDK plug-in.
- After it was completed, the following message appeared:

  ```
  Errors occurred during the build.

  Errors running builder 'Android Resource Manager' on project 'pr1Android'.

  java.lang.NullPointerException
  ```

**From the log file:**

1. Failed to load properties file for project 'pr1Android'
2. Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: `org.eclipse.core.resources`.

   ```
   java.lang.NullPointerException
       at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.BaseBuilder.abortOnBadSetup(BaseBuilder.java:327)
       at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.ResourceManagerBuilder.build(ResourceManagerBuilder.java:92)
       at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:728)
       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
       at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:199)
       at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:239)
       at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:292)
       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
       at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:295)
       at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:351)
       at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:374)
       at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:143)
       at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:241)
       at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
   ```

**Circumstance:**

- Ubuntu 16.04, java 1.8.0_91
- New install of Android SDK and plug-in for Eclipse
- Passed all stages of tutorial of user Casper Ll in:
  [Complete Installation Guide for Android SDK / ADT Bundle on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/318246/complete-installation-guide-for-android-sdk-adt-bundle-on-ubuntu)
- An error at step 7 of the tutorial was solved following the instructions of user kolim in the following:
  https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/145437/reinstall-avd-on-ubuntu-16-04/145690
  it includes to install lib64stdc++6

Comment: What is the Null Pointer Exception Pointing at?  Hint: Post the entire error log.  There could be 50 different places a Null Pointer could occur.

Comment: Thanks user eyoung100.  I edited the original post and it now include the pointer destinations

Comment: Found your answer, but in order to fix it, I need to know your Java version.

Comment: that would be very helpful. java 1.8.0_91

Answer (score 0):

Please note that I have no idea as to the path of your JVM, as I have yet to install Java on my fresh Ubuntu 16.04 VirtualBox image, but this should get you started on the right path (pun intended).

You should have an `eclipse.ini` file located at `$ECLIPSE_HOME/eclipse.ini`

1. Open the above file: `gedit $ECLIPSE_HOME/eclipse.ini`.  For in-depth coverage of the file, refer to the References below.
2. Find the line that reads `-vmargs`.  Insert a blank line above it.
3. On the Blank line add: `-vm`, and hit Enter to create another new line.
4. On the Blank line, enter the `PATH` value for your Java machine, i.e. `/opt/jdk-1.8.0_91/bin/java`.  Please note that the path could be very different.
5. Make sure `JAVA_HOME`and `JDK_HOME` are set. See [How to set JAVA_HOME for Java?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/175514/how-to-set-java-home-for-java).  Be sure to look at the pastebin comment if you have multiple versions.
6. Logout and back in to accept the changes from Step 5.
7. If all works well, I believe you can set `-vm` to the exported value in `JAVA_HOME`.  If that fails after restarting Eclipse, I'll remove this step.

---

Regarding issues with Eclipse, I haven't had any major issues, but for Android Development, I actually prefer [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html), as it's the official IDE endorsed by Android.  The reason you might consider it bloated is because the IDE settings are configured in such a way that the increased bloat is used to support those settings, I.e. type-checking for a hard-coded string, and the integrated layout editor.

### References

[java.lang.NullPointerException when creating first android app in OS X 10.9.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26535927/java-lang-nullpointerexception-when-creating-first-android-app-in-os-x-10-9-4)

[Eclipse Wiki - eclipse.ini](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#-vm_value:_Linux_Example)

Comment: The same problem appears. The change in eclipse.ini already changed (forgot to mention in the post), and now also added the JAVA_HOME and JDK_HOME with the same directory path. You have another idea? Thanks for your effort in any case

Comment: What happens if: 1) You remove the change from my answer? 2) You downgrade Java to JDK/JRE-7?  I have a hunch that you're going to need to try #2 with multiple versions until you find a match that works.  If this is the case the plugin is version specific.

Comment: That would complicate me too much. There could be bugs in java 7 that will retroactively return problems corrected in java 8, with ubuntu 16.04, the IDE, etc.

Comment: @Dan if that's how you feel then remove the plugin, otherwise try the last version of Java 7.  This issue smells of a regression issue.  The only way to test if that's true is to regress Java since you can't upgrade the plugin.  If downgrading solves the issue, then you file a bug for the plugin.  Otherwise try Android studio.