# problem in compiling java program

Tags: java

I'm new to Ubuntu and I have recently made my laptop dual boot Windows 8 and Ubuntu 12.04. I installed java by using the command

`sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk`

It installed successfully. I tried compile java program it shows following message

```
a@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ javac hello.java
The program 'javac' can be found in the following packages:
* default-jdk
* ecj
* gcj-4.6-jdk
* openjdk-6-jdk
* gcj-4.5-jdk
* openjdk-7-jdk
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

Please suggest what to do???
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your `jdk` installation was proper and `JAVA_HOME` is not set as Environment variable. To set `JAVA_HOME` variable follow the below steps

1. Open terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> +  <kbd>T</kbd> )
2. Edit the environment file using the command

   ```
   $ sudo gedit /etc/environment
   ```

   or you can use `nano` editor as your wish.
3. At the end of the file paste the following lines

   ```
   JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/open-jdk"
   export JAVA_HOME
   ```

   **Note:** The `JAVA_HOME` path depends on installtion path of `jdk`.
4. Save the file and exit from `gedit`.
5. Use the following command to reload Environment variable changes,

   ```
   $ source /etc/environment
   ```
6. Now check the `jdk` path using the command

   ```
   $ echo $JAVA_HOME
   ```

or use

```
    $ java -version
```

The above command will give you the installed `jdk` version if it's installed properly.

If it's not working reboot your system once.

For more info see this [How to set JAVA_HOME for Java?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/175514/how-to-set-java-home-for-java)