# Problem launching eclipse in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, java, eclipse, openjdk

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 I have installed openJDK via synaptic and also eclipse via synaptic. Everything was working fine. However suddenly I am getting this error when I try to open eclipse.

[image: error code]

How to fix this?

The out put of

```
dpkg -l libtomcat7-java
```

is

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig- aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-    =================================
ii  libtomcat7-jav 7.0.68-1ubun all          Servlet and JSP engine -- core li
```

The content of my eclipse.ini is:

```
 -startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.dist.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.dist
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Xms40m
-Xmx384m
-    Dorg.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins.directory=/usr/share/eclipse/dropins
```

Comment: That looks like the arguments to Java, not the error. Is there more to the output than that?

Comment: @ManojSawai Thanks, but can you help me to get working official repository eclipse?

Comment: @JosephSible Unfortunately no, when i open eclipse from dash only this window I get.

Comment: Perhaps if you were to [edit] in the content of your log file at ${location of the workspace}/.metadata/.log it would help us help you! Thank you!

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28406104/eclipse-cannot-start-jvm-exit-code-1

Comment: I have this problem on my Raspberry Pi 3. It hangs, and that message pops up when I kill it. So glad to see a bounty!

Comment: @ElderGeek I added the screenshot, this is the only thing I am getting. Even the option of creating a workspace does not come

Comment: Does the related link I posted provide any clues?

Comment: @ElderGeek I have nothing else other than this screenshot

Comment: Not my strongest suit but if I'm parsing the output correctly it looks like you might be trying to activate plugins from an earlier distribution. (1.1 vs. 3.8) I did find that the file /usr/lib/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.platform_3.8.1.dist/splash.bmp  comes from the package [eclipse-platform-data](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=org.eclipse.platform_3.8.1.dist%2Fsplash.bmp&mode=exactfilename&suite=xenial&arch=any) which is the Eclipse platform without development plug-ins.  Would you be so kind as to [edit] the output of `dpkg -l libtomcat7-java` into your post?

Comment: @ElderGeek updated my post

Comment: Well you have the prerequisite installed for that package. Could you also [edit] in the content of $ECLIPSE_HOME/eclipse.ini. or If $ECLIPSE_HOME is not defined, the default eclipse.ini in your Eclipse installation directory? I'm hoping to find some clues comparing that to [this](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini) Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: @ElderGeek updated my question

Answer (score 5):

Upon review of your eclipse.ini file it seems that we haven't specified a specific Java Virtual Machine to run eclipse on. This is appears to be a common stumbling block. Let's remove the uncertainty by explicitly stating which VM to use by placing the -vm argument in your eclipse.ini

It's always a good idea to make a backup if you aren't entirely certain what you are doing, so from the directory containing your eclipse.ini make a copy with cp eclipse.ini ~/Documents/eclipse.bak which will place a backup in your Documents directory.

Locate the version of java you intend to launch [this may help](https://superuser.com/questions/357234/how-to-know-the-jvm-path-in-a-linux-system) and if the results are confusing [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19467761/which-java-in-centos-prints-wrong-java-path) should help provide clarity. Don't skim, read both the [accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19467890/3816360) and [highest rated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19467814/3816360) answers

Specify the full path to the vm your trying to launch.

Example **your path is likely different**:

```
-vm
/opt/sun-jdk-1.6.0.02/bin/java
```

Place the appropriate lines for your installation directly before the -vmargs line as shown in the Specifying the JVM section [here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini)

Sources:

https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini

https://superuser.com/questions/357234/how-to-know-the-jvm-path-in-a-linux-system

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19467761/which-java-in-centos-prints-wrong-java-path

Also of interest:

[How to set JAVA_HOME for Java?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/175514/how-to-set-java-home-for-java)