# No java command after installing JDK

Tags: 16.04, java, jdk, jre

I have downloaded and installed JDK 9 with NetBeans. NetBeans runs fine and I build test application that also runs fine from IDE. But if I run `java` command in terminal I have error

```
'java' can not be found in the following package:
...
```

So, where is my java? Should I download JRE separately?

Command

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

gives

```
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for java
```

Comment: How did you install JDK 9 and Netbeans?

Answer (score 0):

Edit your .bashrc file by

```
gedit .bashrc
```

Add these line at the last of the file

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0
```

(this path may change according to your system)

(this you copy as it is)

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export JAVA_HOME
export JRE_HOME
export PATH
```

then logout and login

Comment: To make this a useful answer, you may consider adding the information why this is needed and how to achieve it.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/175514/how-to-set-java-home-for-java                     go to the link and follow steps

Comment: I have updated my /etc/environment with line
JAVA_HOME="usr/local/jdk1.8.0_151/"
and executed command
source /etc/environment
But java command still not recognized

Comment: @vico you entered an invalid path. It's a good idea not to edit `/etc/environment` at all. I suggest putting the assignment in your `.profile`. But don't forget the leading `/`