# Oracle Java JDK 9 unable to install via tar

Tags: software-installation, java, jdk, oracle

I need Oracle JDK and JRE so i downloaded tar.gz from Oracle downloads page
Extracted using `tar zxvf jdk-9.0.4_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz` as described here
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/install/installation-jdk-and-jre-linux-platforms.htm#JSJIG-GUID-ADC9C14A-5F51-4C32-802C-9639A947317F

But when i type java -version i am getting this error:

[image: image here]

1. Why its not working, what are the actual steps to install Oracle jdk9 properly as above steps are not working
2. I also want jdk and jre(Oracle only) both installed via tar and accessed with java -version and JAVA_HOME set.
3. As you can see I `cd` into `jdk -> bin` and typed `java -version` but its not working, I wonder why is that? this is where actual binaries lives.

[image: image here]

Answer (score 0):

Java is one of the many commands which can be installed to / configured (selected) in /etc/alternatives/

Java 9 example

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/java/jdk-9.0.4/bin/java 1
$ sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /usr/java/jdk-9.0.4/bin/javac 2
```

If more than one version, please select with :

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

Comment: JAVA_HOME setting : https://askubuntu.com/questions/175514/how-to-set-java-home-for-java ... `JAVA_HOME="/usr/java/jdk-9.0.4"`