# The spurious JAVA_HOME

Tags: java, eclipse, environment-variables

*(I have already taken a look at [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/175514/82650).)*

For at least one application in my system, I am getting an obstinate JAVA_HOME value which I can not seem to change.

*Java installed in my system*

- For me:

  ```
  $ which java        
  /opt/jdk-10.0.1/bin/java
  ```
- For the `root` user:

  ```
  # which java
  /opt/jdk-10.0.1/bin/java
  ```

*Value of `JAVA_HOME`*

- For me:

  ```
  $ printenv JAVA_HOME
  /opt/jdk-10.0.1/
  ```
- For the `root` user:

  ```
  # printenv JAVA_HOME
  /opt/jdk-10.0.1
  ```

*Java alternatives*

```
    $ sudo update-alternatives --config java
    update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for java
```

*The places where I have set the value of this environment variable*

- In `/etc/environment`

  ```
  JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk-10.0.1
  ```
- In the `.profile` file in my home

  ```
  export JAVA_HOME="/opt/jdk-10.0.1"
  ```

---

*The problem*

When I execute `~/eclipse/php-oxygen2/eclipse/eclipse` for [eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-php-developers/oxygen3a), it executes successfully. But for the command, `~/eclipse/php-oxygen/eclipse/eclipse`, coming from the same package, I get the following error:

[image]

I am at a loss to find out how the above value
has been set.

Even the following command,

```
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk-10.0.1/; ~/eclipse/php-oxygen/eclipse/eclipse
```

produces the same error.

Could somebody please tell me where else can I look to find the source of this spurious value? Eclipse does not have an option in preferences to set
`JAVA_HOME` (internally).

Comment: Remove the "oracle-java8-set-default" package.

Comment: @Logix `sudo apt-get purge oracle-java8-set-default`, `sudo apt-get purge oracle-java8*`, `sudo apt-get purge java8*`. None of these worked. Some thing in the line, `Package 'oracle-java8-jdk' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'oracle-java8-installer' is not installed, so not removed`.

Comment: Just "sudo apt purge oracle-java8-set-default". That's all that should be needed, that's the package that makes Oracle Java 8 default.

Comment: @Logix sudo apt purge oracle-java8-set-default
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package oracle-java8-set-default