# JAVA_HOME keeps being deleted despite i set it

Tags: java

```
â caner@vegan  ~  echo   $JAVA_HOME 

â caner@vegan  ~  echo $PATH     
/home/caner/bin:/home/caner/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
â caner@vegan  ~
```

this is now empty.

```
â caner@vegan  ~    export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_171  
â caner@vegan  ~    export PATH="$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin"           
â caner@vegan  ~  echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_171
â caner@vegan  ~  echo $PATH     
/home/caner/bin:/home/caner/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_171/bin
â caner@vegan  ~
```

now i set values. BUt after minutes, it keeps getting unset. As first codes show.

Why is that?

it is ubntu 16.04.

I run some ant commands for hybris but i am not sure if it is about it.

Comment: Does it happen if you don't run any command? Are you sure you are in the same shell process (or child process) when the variables have been "reset"?

Comment: For example, in same command which i wrote those in the question, it seems setted. BUt when i open a new terminal, now i saw that it is empty. Now i noticed that, when i set javahome, in new terminal i see it is empty. @danzel this did not work https://askubuntu.com/a/175547/539466

Comment: That is how environment variables work. Which terminal emulator and shell do you use?

Comment: I am using yakuake with zsh. I noticed also i cant open default terminal.  when i try gnome from akuake, it says `â caner@vegan  ~  gnome-terminal
Error constructing proxy for org.gnome.Terminal:/org/gnome/Terminal/Factory0: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.gnome.Terminal: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.gnome.Terminal exited with status 8
` i downloaded jdk 8 only and gave its path.

Comment: Then you have to add the `source /etc/environment` line to `~/.zshrc` (because, well, zsh not bash). I've seen a question some days ago regarding the error you described, just search on AskUbuntu.

Comment: @danzel i added this line `# If you come from bash you might have to change your $PATH.
# export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH

source /etc/environment
` then again export path and javahome and then  `source ~/.zshrc` but it did not work again when i opend new terminal tab :(

Comment: You need to export the environment variables in `/etc/environment` (add the `export PATH=...` lines to that file). Then you add the `source ...` line to `~/.zshrc`. Now if you open a new terminal, the variables should be set.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78536/discussion-between-danzel-and-cursedchico).

Comment: I added to `etc/profile` those `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_17
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH` then source it and zsh but even in that terminal, jvahome is still empty. Before,  i added to zshrc this `
source /etc/environment
`  then path became this `$ echo $PATH                      
/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_17/bin:/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_17/bin:/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_17/bin:/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_17/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/....
`. i did source to zsh,env and profile. After i source enviroment,  javahome is being deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I did those steps.

I went to

```
sudo nano /etc/environment
```

I added those

```
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_171"
export ANT_HOME="/usr/local/ant"

export PATH=$ANT_HOME/bin:$PATH
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

This sets globally.

But for terminal, it has to refresh this , for example when i open a new terminal.

So i also added bottom of my zsh configuration:

```
sudo nano ~/.zshrc
```

this

```
 source /etc/environment
```

and now it works.