# How do I install the necessary JRE to run Minecraft

Tags: java, minecraft

I am trying to install JRE 8 to use minecraft, but I got a .tar.gz file. I have extracted the file, it is called JRE1.8.0_201 on my desktop, but I don't know what to do. **Can I please have some help here? The guides I have looked at don't show what to do in a clear way.**

Comment: After you upack the tarball `tar zxvf jre-8u73-linux-x64.tar.gz` you can simply set a path to use it https://askubuntu.com/questions/175514/how-to-set-java-home-for-java

Comment: Using Apt Source is easiest by far....

Answer (score 2):

If you download and install the latest Minecraft.deb package from minecraft.net, all necessary dependencies will be installed, including jre 8.

To install jre 8 manually, you can use the version available in pre-configured apt sources:

```
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre
```

And to install the latest jre:

```
sudo apt install openjdk-11-jre
```