# How do I update Java to 8u51 on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: updates, firefox, java, oracle

I'm a casual Linux user and recently Firefox started sending me a bunch of vulnerability warnings (as in, even more than anything I had experienced before) regarding my current Java version (8u45), which led me to my issue at hand.

First, I tried using this method: [HowTo: Upgrade java on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/508546/howto-upgrade-java-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts) but it didn't work. Even after uninstalling Java 8 completely and installing it again from scratch ended at the same version as before (8u45).

Then I went to the Java website and downloaded the .tar directly from there. But even after following the instructions, nothing seemed to happen.

So, what now? Do I keep using my current version and ignore the dozens of warnings Firefox is giving me? Is there something else I can try? Or am I locked out of anything Java related for god knows how long?

Answer (score 0):

The [WebUpd8 PPA](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java) is not updated any more.

You can update java to 8u51 using a script.

```
sudo apt-get install git curl
git clone https://github.com/hanipouspilot/oracle-java8.git
sudo sh oracle-java8/javains
```

This is only for 64-bit Ubuntu.

The problem is that Oracle changes links used in this script and I do not guarantee that I will update the script for the future updates. But I probably will if there is no a better solution.

Comment: Running `sudo sh oracle-java8/javains` results in `oracle-java8/javains: 5: oracle-java8/javains: curl: not found`

Comment: I updated the answer. Run `sudo apt-get install curl` and try again to run the script.

Answer (score 0):

to confirm that your java version is configured correctly, look [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/659511/437967)
but ignore the R config.

for assistance with the FireFox plugin have a look at this [post](https://askubuntu.com/a/660148/437967)